# Stdout in IPython notebook vs CLI IPython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Results of commands are not displayed when run from a notebook cell.

From IPython notebook:

`os.system("pwd")`
`0`       <-- no errors

From IPython invoked from CLI:

`In [15]: os.system("pwd")`
`/Users/joe`
`Out[15]: 0`  <-- no errors

I expected to see `/Users/joe` displayed when command runs from a notebook cell.
What's missing?

Thank you,
I.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2012-February/009418.html):

> When you do os.system, it's not capturing stdout/stderr from the new
>   process. In the terminal, this works, because stdout and stderr just
>   go directly to the terminal, without Python ever knowing about them.
>   In the notebook, it doesn't, because the kernel can only forward
>   stdout/stderr that it knows about.

The solution to the problem is to use `subprocess`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(["pwd"])
/Users/joe
```

Comment: In principle, ipython notebook could have [redirected stdout to a socket (`.fileno()`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) (on posixy systems) and displayed that).

Comment: @elyase: Can you expand on why Python does not know about the stdout when invoked from a notebook?

Comment: @flamenco, It doesn't know about it on the terminal either but there you are a least able to see it. Imagine you call a C program which suddenly decides to make a sound, print or draw something in the screen using a low level API, there are workarounds but it is just not trivial to capture it from Python who is not even aware that happened. Python just told the system "run the program", but it can only exert control over the execution up to a certain level. For a more in depth discussion take a look [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1230).

Answer (score 4):

IPython (Notebook) has a solution for this:

```
In [1]: %pwd

'/Users/xxx/tmp'
```

You can also call any shell command:

```
In [2]: !pwd

'/Users/xxx/tmp'
```

In the notebook you can also run a whole cell with `bash` commands:

```
In [3]: %%bash
        pwd 
        ls

'/Users/xxx/tmp'
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

Comment: @flamenco Did you try one of these approaches?